# scapy.srp() doesn't responds with expected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, arp, network-scan

I am trying to code of network scanner and further once I try to print the response, it does not show anything.

```
import scapy.all as scapy


def scan(ip):
    packet1 = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    etherpacket = scapy.Ether(dst = 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')

    broadcast_packet = etherpacket/packet1
    ans, unans = scapy.srp(broadcast_packet, timeout=10)

    print(ans.summary())





scan("192.168.1.1-254")
```

Below is the result.

```
$sudo python3 networkscanner.py 
Begin emission:
........Finished sending 1 packets.
..........
Received 18 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
None
```

Comment: Scapy may be using the wrong interface, one thing you can do is pass an explicit interface name to `srp` using the `iface` parameter. `conf.iface` will tell you the default interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change shall be in when the function is called, it should be /24 not the way written above.

```
import scapy.all as scapy


    def scan(ip):
        packet1 = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
        etherpacket = scapy.Ether(dst = 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')

        broadcast_packet = etherpacket/packet1
        ans, unans = scapy.srp(broadcast_packet, timeout=10)

        print(ans.summary())





    scan("192.168.1.1/24")
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "Operation not permitted"

Answer (score 0):

Use scapy's built-in `arping` instead to do an ARP scan:

```py
from scapy.all import arping

arping("192.168.1.0/24")
```

Then in your shell:

```sh
$ python3 arping.py
Begin emission:
*****************Finished sending 256 packets.

Received 17 packets, got 17 answers, remaining 239 packets
  00:1b:78:20:ee:40 192.168.1.48
  a4:77:33:88:92:62 192.168.1.66
  6c:33:a9:42:6a:18 192.168.1.67
...
```

Arping docs are [here](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.l2.html#scapy.layers.l2.arping).